# WCF - Viewing xml request/response to a secure webservice

Tags: c#, .net, xml, wcf

I have a WCF service application and in this app I am doing calls to a third party web service over a secure connection.

I have been trying to view the request response streams using fiddler but I have given up on it after trying more than half day applying all I could find over the internet. It has a problem with certificates eventhough I did more fiddlers certificates to trusted zone.

What is my best bet to simply see the xml requests and responses that I am making to this third party web service?

I am using generated proxy classes so I don't currently have access to the raw xml that I am sending and receiving back. I am curious if I am over complicating something which can be done much simpler. This is my development machine and I have access to pretty much everything, no restrictions.

A simple way to do this please?

EDIT:

At this moment I don't even need to use Tracing. I just need to see the serialized output of my request/response. Even if I can do this from the Visual Studio debugger or such It will help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since I was trying to read the soap messages to and from the asmx web service that is referenced to my WCF app, the solution to my problem was to create a class that inherits from System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapExtension, register this class in the web.config so that all traffic is routed through this class and viewed.

None of this communication would show up on the WCF traces so that was not enough. However it was useful that I learned it so now I am able to see all that is going on between my wcf service app and web app..

This article nailed it for me [how-to-capture-soap-envelopes-when-consuming-a-web-service](http://www.blog.encoresystems.net/articles/how-to-capture-soap-envelopes-when-consuming-a-web-service.aspx)

Comment: Link didn't work for me, but this one did: http://blog.encoresystems.net/articles/how-to-capture-soap-envelopes-when-consuming-a-web-service.aspx

Answer (score 8):

Use [WCF Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx) - it works very well and comes with a handy [trace viewer utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023.aspx).

You can set up loads of options - but at its core, you'll have to add something like this to your WCF service and client configs:

```
<configuration>
   <system.diagnostics>
      <sources>
            <source name="System.ServiceModel" 
                    switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
                    propagateActivity="true">
            <listeners>
               <add name="traceListener" 
                   type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" 
                   initializeData= "c:\log\Traces.svclog" />
            </listeners>
         </source>
      </sources>
   </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

There's a variety of "trace listeners" out of the box - one writes to the output console in Visual Studio, this one here is creating XML files, or you can store stuff in a SQL Server database table - and the whole mechanism is extensible, you can write your own trace listeners, too!

Also see here: [Using of WCF Trace](http://developers.de/blogs/damir_dobric/archive/2009/03/24/using-of-wcf-trace.aspx) and here [WCF Tracing FAQ](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/WCFTracingFAQ.aspx) for more info.

Comment: I set it up this way but the traces contain nothing about the communication between my app and the 3rd party web service... Could it be due to SSL??

Comment: is the communication between "your app and the 3rd party webservice" a WCF call? Then you definitely should see entries in your WCF log.

Comment: 3rd party is a web service added as a web reference to my wcf app. And my app is sending requests and receiving responses from that service. Any req/resp parameter info from this communication is definitely not existing in traces. I have done find/search operations on the trace even with notepad and no trace of any of my req/resp objects or values in the log. Currently implementing Interceptor behavior to intercept messages, hopefully this will give me what I need..

Comment: @Kaivalya: if you could add it as a WCF **service** reference, you could trace the traffic going over it with WCF tracing....

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your app.config:

```
<system.diagnostics>
<sources>
  <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
    <listeners>
      <add name="messages" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="messages.svclog" />
     </listeners>
  </source>
</sources>
```

```
<system.serviceModel>
<diagnostics>
  <messageLogging
       logEntireMessage="true"
       logMalformedMessages="true"
       logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true"
       logMessagesAtTransportLevel="false"
       maxMessagesToLog="-1"/>
</diagnostics>
```

It will log all messages to messages.svclog. You can then view them.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/diagnostics/configuring-message-logging